# How to get current object reference inside a jquery callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript Object called `aObject` and a fucntion inside it is used as a jQuery Callback function like this:

```
var aObject = {
    aVariable : 'whatever value',
    test : function(e) {
        // Trying to access property. But doesn't work as expected since I am getting the DOM element i.e form, not the aObject reference
        var temp = this.aVariable;
    }
}

$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#some-html-form').submit(aObject.test);
});
```

When I call the test method in `aObject`, this refers to the form element that has been submitted. I want to access current object from the `test` callback function?

I tried the below code as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7304494/3302016) answer but it did not work for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#add_api_form').submit(api_cahce.handle_add_form_submit.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: Does using `this` not work? If that doesn't work it could be because the object you think you are referring to using `this` is not the object you are actually referring to.

Comment: No, this referes to the DOM element as test is a callback function.

Comment: @Mohan you need to bind the aObject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind with `aObject` then you can access the variable.

```
var aObject = {
    aVariable : 'whatever value',
    test : function(e) {
        var temp = this.aVariable;
    }
}

$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#some-html-form').submit(aObject.test.bind(aObject));
});
```

Comment: Does not work. On submit the call back function is not being called & the form gets submitted directly.

Comment: @Mohan i will modify the answer.

Comment: actually it worked. there was some error in other line

Comment: @Mohan ohk.happy coding